# Merge sort same output C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, vector, mergesort

I wrote the below code for merge sort but it's not working, And I am unable to find out problem!
Every time the output becomes same as input, I think that problem may occur due to vector reference.
I think mergeSort is not creating a new vector for sub array. But I am still confused.

input vector: `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`
output: `5, 4, 3, 2, 1`
Req output: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void merge(vector<int> &la, vector<int> &ra, vector<int> &A) {

    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    //  overwriting A using its solved sub arrays i.e la, ra
    while (i < la.size() && j < ra.size()) {
        if (la[i] <= ra[j]) {
            A[k] = la[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else {
            A[k] = ra[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    //  if any subarray left then
    while (i < la.size()) {
        A[k] = la[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < ra.size()) {
        A[k] = ra[j];
        k++;
        j++;    
    }
}
```

mergeSort function:

```
void mergeSort(vector<int> &A) {

    if (A.size() < 2)
        return;

    int len = A.size();
    vector<int> la, ra;

    for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++)
        la.push_back(A[i]);

    for (int i = len / 2; i < len; i++)
        ra.push_back(A[i]);

    //  dividing the proble into subproblem
    mergeSort(la);
    mergeSort(ra);

    //  merging the solved subproblem
    merge(la, ra, A);
}
```

Driver function:

```
int main(void) {
    int arr[] = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    vector<int> A(arr, arr + 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    mergeSort(A);

    for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++)
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're passing vectors **by copy** to `mergeSort` and `merge`. Pass them by reference (`&`) instead.

Comment: Try to write more clear titles for your questions, so that every body can find their problem.

Comment: @Botje i have tried by passing the reference also, but it still not working.

Comment: "not working" is a useless diagnostic. Edit your code to use references and show us what you observed and expected to happen.

Comment: @Botje I have make changes in my code you can see, it still giving the same output.

Comment: @Ujjwal.Maurya0619 The version as posted works for me (ie produces 1 2 3 4 5 on the second line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted does not seem to have a problem.

Executing it produces the expected output: `1 2 3 4 5`, so there is something else going on that could cause your observations: you might be running an executable produced by a previous or at least different version of the code.